# How to write a recursive method that would print out an integer in words?

Tags: recursion, methods

For example, if I put 123, the return String would be one two three?

Comment: what did you try and why did it not work?

Comment: Please explain your question more clearly. For example, which programming language you need?

Comment: recursive methods work like that: divide the problem into smaller subproblems (e.g. how do you print one digit) and then combine them into one solution. Make sure that your program terminates at some point

Comment: Why must it be recursive? From what you gave, it can be as simple as a chained replace.

Answer (score 1):

One of the ways we could do this is mathematical

1. Reverse the input(number) by using % and / operators. For example, if the input is 123, make it 321.
2. Break each digit of reversed number from right side using / and % operators and use  else if or switch case method to print that each digit in words.